# Least and Greatest functions are giving wrong values for negative values

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I tried to use Greatest and Least function in my code to create a range, it's working for positive values but for negative values, it's not working.

If I take -100 and -1, then I get output as -1 as least and -100 as greatest value.

Here is part of code of my procedure:

```
i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT    IN OUT        VARCHAR2,
i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT_2  IN OUT        VARCHAR2

        If ((i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT is not null) OR (i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT is not null)) Then
                select least(i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT,i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT_2) into v_Min_Amount from dual;
                select greatest(i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT,i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT_2) into v_Max_Amount from dual;
                
                i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT := v_Min_Amount;
                i_FILTER_TRANS_AMOUNT_2 :=  v_Max_Amount;
        End If;
```

Comment: Because you are using strings instead of numbers.  Simply use the correct data type.

Comment: if i convert it from string to number ? my procedure is called by dotnet program which call with varchar in values and takes the output also in varchar

Comment: Also correct your If condition. You are using same variables in both conditions.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yeah you correct i already changed but that will not resolve main issue

Comment: Try using to_number function. If you have to pass the varchar values from front-end.

Comment: I just changed the data type as numbers in pleace of Varchar2, Its working fine now.

Comment: By the way, PL/SQL syntax doesn't require brackets around IF conditions. You can write `if i_filter_trans_amount is not null or i_filter_trans_amount is not null` without all the brackets.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson brackets are helping easier review and read..will it effect the performance?

Comment: @vim No, it will not affect performance if you do or do not use brackets. If it makes it easier for you to review and read then, for that reason, you should use brackets.